fs.write() vs fs.writeFile() vs fs.appendFile()
What is the difference between fs.write(), fs.writeFile() and fs.appendFile()?
I'm having some trouble understanding what exactly the difference between these 3 methods is because to me, they ultimately look the same, or rather like shortcuts to one another.
From the base description of fs.write() and fs.writeFile() they seem the same, noticeable differences are the number of parameters, fs.writeFile() has more. But then in the description of fs.writeFile() it says

Similarly to fs.readFile - fs.writeFile is a convenience method that performs multiple write calls internally to write the buffer passed to it.

So it's just a faster and automatic way to call multiple fs.write()? Which brings us to fs.appendFile(), because that just seems like a shortcut for fs.writeFile() with the a flag set. The only difference I can see are the default set flags and the number of types you can use for the data.
Then there would also be fs.createWriteStream(), but that clearly differentiates itself
in several ways and has a different use case than the write() methods, like a logger that has to write fast and often, so I do get the difference there.

fs.write seems to a low-level API similar to how programming languages like C handles files. fs.writeFile splits the data for you and saves it

fs.write()'s first argument must be a file descriptor, which will be provided by fs.open but fs.writeFile() can take file descriptor or file path.
Also docs mentions

Using fs.writeFile() with file descriptors
The difference from directly calling fs.write() is that under some unusual conditions, fs.write() might write only part of the buffer and need to be retried to write the remaining data, whereas fs.writeFile() retries until the data is entirely written (or an error occurs).


fs.appendFile(), because that just seems like a shortcut for fs.writeFile() with the a flag set. The only difference I can see are the default set flags and the number of types you can use for the data.

Yes,
here is source of fs.appendFile
// below function is output of process.stdout.write(fs.appendFile.toString())

function appendFile(path, data, options, callback) {
  callback = maybeCallback(callback || options);
  options = getOptions(options, { encoding: 'utf8', mode: 0o666, flag: 'a' });

  // Don't make changes directly on options object
  options = copyObject(options);

  // Force append behavior when using a supplied file descriptor
  if (!options.flag || isFd(path))
    options.flag = 'a';

  fs.writeFile(path, data, options, callback);
}



Where is this snippet from?

@Konrad just paste this in line node REPL process.stdout.write(fs.appendFile.toString()). You can view javascript function body by converting into string. It only works for pure js functions, but some inbuilt functions are written in C++, where it won't work.

So basically fs.writeFile builds onto fs.write() with more parameters and types of parameters? And if you call appendFile with the w flag, it would be the same as writeFile?

@GreenSaiko fs.writeFile is fs.write with additional steps ensuring buffer is written, I recommend using fs.writeFile, use fs.write() if you know what you are doing.

@GreenSaiko No appendFile with w flag won't work as writeFile since there is a line in appendFIle function that overrides flag with 'a'. (its in the snippet I have shared)

@bogdanoff I saw that line, but doesn't that only apply when we either set no flags or call appendFile with a file descriptor? So calling it with the 'w' flag and using a path it should not be overriden right?

@GreenSaiko no not that line, 3rd line in function body with call to getOptions. getOptions ~~takes two objects and mergers it, overriding flag option~~ . I guess you are still right, just looked definition of getOptions and  it does not merge options so passing with  'w' flag won't be overridden i guess, thus acting as fs.writeFile instead of fs.appendFile.
